# 'rasa run actions & rasa shell' FREEZING the terminal

Tags: rasa-nlu, rasa-core, rasa, rasa-x, nlu

When I am trying to run the command `rasa run actions & rasa shell` in the terminal for running `rasa actions file`, my terminal is freezing and the endpoint server is not starting. The terminal freezes at this point:

`(rasa2) C:\Users\nabaj\source\repos\rasa2>rasa run actions & rasa shell 2020-07-17 16:52:26 INFO    rasa_sdk.endpoint  - Starting action endpoint server... 2020-07-17 16:52:26 INFO    rasa_sdk.executor  - Registered function for 'action_check_search'.`

Have tried it multiple times and even on different systems but the issue still persists.

[snapshot of the terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5X4RA.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been solved. I ran `rasa run` and `rasa shell` in two different terminals. It worked. For more reference check this [rasa forum page](https://forum.rasa.com/t/rasa-run-actions-rasa-shell-is-freezing-the-terminal/31439/2)